# Ubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu Mate, Kubuntu installation hangs: Version 15.04

Tags: xubuntu, 15.04, lubuntu, kubuntu, mate

I have been trying to install several of the 15.04 ubuntu based distros recently and noticed that they all hang on the installation step where you are asked if you would like to download updates while installing and install the 3rd party software for mp3 support.

I have tried this on 2 of my computers, a desktop and a laptop and get the same result, ie: the installation just seems to enter an infinite loop of doing nothing when you click "next".

I found that the solution is to "uncheck" the "install 3rd party drivers for mp3 support" option. This enabled me to continue with the installation without problems.

I thought I should put this information in the public domain as this problem caused me a lot of difficulty for several days.

However, now the 3rd party drivers for mp3 support are not installed.

So, questions:

- How can I install them using `apt-get`?
- Is there another solution to this problem.
- This seems like quite a severe problem, do the ubuntu developers know about it? (Or if not how can I report it?)

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

This command should install all the stuff you need to play mp3 files (and some more).